# On a UK Tier 2 Visa, can I have a 2nd job outside the country?

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas, uk-visa

Hi all & thanks in advance for reading.

My question is basically summed up in the title, I have read the [gov.uk information](https://www.gov.uk/tier-2-general/second-job) regarding holding a 2nd job and understand that I could work in the same profession within the country. I'm wondering if anyone has advice about my eligibility to work outside my profession within another country? I am a software developer but am looking at doing some online translation/transcription work sporadically for a US company just for a bit of extra cash on the side.

Comment: Nothing in the linked page (which is about "Second Job") says anything about having to work within the country. If your primary work satisfies the terms of your Tier 2 visa, why do you conclude your second employment must be in-country?

Comment: Well, I don't and that's essentially my question. Does a second job mean a job I hold anywhere in the world and then, as such, am I restricted by my visa to only ever hold a job within the one profession?

Comment: Would you be doing the online translation/transcription from inside the UK? In that case it's not a job "outside the country". Remote work from the UK counts as work in the UK. As for whether this specifically would be permitted, I'd be inclined to get actual legal advice about it.